# Re-factoring this mysql table display code

Tags: php, mysql, function, html-table

I'm not wholly proficient with PHP but I'm having a few problems echoing a gathered value from a MySQL query function.

I believe I know where the problem lies but I'm not competent enough to fix it, if you could please help it would be appreciated.

**PHP Function** (Works perfectly).

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT Name, Role, Salary FROM `users-table`';

mysql_select_db('user_records');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "--------------------------------<br>",
         "Name: {$row['Name']}  <br> ".
         "Role: {$row['Role']} <br> ".
         "Salary : {$row['Salary']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

This displays the data perfectly! However I'm now trying to include this in a nicely formatted HTML table. (Which is why I'm closing the php tag above).

I'm then trying to use a table like this:

```
<table >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['Name'] ?>
            </td>
....
```

It outputs nothing, - I think this problem is caused because I close the first function and then try to reference `$row` and it doesn't know what to do...?

I think I need to tap in to `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))`
How can I re-factor this so that I can echo content from the above function to my table?

Comment: [Please, stop using mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1238019) in new code, they are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Instead of, have a look on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), and use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: You'd loop through rows in between the table tags...

Comment: @zessx I will move away, I'm just tinkering and learning as I go. I will look into MySQLi, this is just a problem that's annoying me.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write the code you tried, but here is something functional:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost", "myuser", "mypassw", "mybd");
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($link, $retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Role']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Salary']}</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**PS:** Since MySQL is deprecated, I replaced your code with `MySQLi`, and I suggest you do the same :)

Comment: What if I wanted to include a table style sheet?

Comment: You mean a stylesheet ? Nothing is stopping you :)

Comment: Sorry, just trying to understand, this interweave of php and html confuses me ;) - I can't see where you're declaring the MySQL table in the above snippet. You're declaring the DB in the first line but what about the actual table?

Answer (score 0):

As @zessx said, yous should use MySQLi or PDO.

anyway to answer to your question, you have to change the loop in your php code from

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "--------------------------------<br>",
         "Name: {$row['Name']}  <br> ".
         "Role: {$row['Role']} <br> ".
         "Salary : {$row['Salary']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
}
```

to

```
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "  <tr>" . 
         "    <td>Name: {$row['Name']}</td>".
         "    <td>Role: {$row['Role']}</td>".
         "    <td>Salary : {$row['Salary']}</td>".
         "  </tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```